# nagios alerts with yowsup-cli

Tags: nagios, yowsup

I've created the following command to send nagios alerts via whatsapp. This command sends the alerts to a whatsapp group.

```
/usr/bin/yowsup-cli demos -c /etc/yowsup-cli.conf -s 49phonenumber-1471509469 '***** NAGIOS Notification ***** -- Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ -- Service: $SERVICEDESC$ -- Host: $HOSTALIAS$ -- Address: $HOSTADDRESS$ -- State: $SERVICESTATE$ -- Date/Time: $LONGDATETIME$ -- Additional Info: $SERVICEOUTPUT$ -- Duration: $SERVICEDURATION$'
```

Now, when it is executed from nagios it doesn't work, but a similar command from the shell works without issues.

```
yowsup-cli demos -c /etc/yowsup-cli.conf -s 49phonenumber-1471509469 "text to send"
```

On the nagios logs there is no error related to this command. Is there anything I'm missing here. 
Please help.
thanks.

Comment: Enable debugging in Nagios and check the debug file instead.

Comment: I did but it doesn't show any error in the debug as well. The command is executed normally. I can see the "message sent" for yowsup but I'm not receiving it. Could it be that nagios treats the "-" character differently. Maybe I need to escape it?

Comment: I was able to fix by adding the "-M" parameter to yowsup-cli command.

Comment: what does -M parameter stand for?